# Refresh page after Navigator popUntil

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `popUntil` to go back to first route by using this code:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
```

Now how can I refresh the current first page?

Comment: I think it depends on what state management you are using? But if you want to load it again you can call pushReplacement() or pushReplacementNamed() when leaving the page, and when you want to go back just push it on top of the Stack so that it loads again.

Comment: @Igniti0n pushReplacement() works for 1 pop but if you have two or more pages in the stack it remains on backpressed.

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Refresh on Go Back',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int id = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Data: $id',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              child: Text('Second Page'),
              onPressed: navigateSecondPage,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void refreshData() {
    id++;
  }

  onGoBack(dynamic value) {
    refreshData();
    setState(() {});
  }

  void navigateSecondPage() {
    Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage());
    Navigator.push(context, route).then(onGoBack);
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
          },
          child: Text('Go Back'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Link: https://codepen.io/nitishk72/pen/YzwGELX

As you can see it uses `.then()` after `Navigator.push()` to call the `onGoBack` function.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nPSU.gif

Comment: I have seen this answer before, it only solves the issue for popping one page back but for multiple pages on the back stack it remains on backpressed.

Comment: i added a GIF. its an app that has more than 2 pages on the stack and it works properly

Comment: Yes this should work. Sorry I didn't check the answer properly to see that you used popUntil in your code. I'll try and fix it. Thank you for the answer. I'll mark correct once I solve it.

Comment: the code that you provide is not the same as on GIF. can you provide the code that contains ThridPage?

Comment: It Works as expected, Thanks.